# Sliding ListView items in React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app and I'm trying to build it with as minimal packages/dependencies as I can.

I have this ListView with items, and I want to be able to slide these items to left or right; making them disappear or have some secondary option come up.

How do I do this without using someone else's prebuilt ListView replacement with this feature?

Comment: please provide some code so we can help you

Comment: Look into the Animated library, and the panhandler library.

Comment: Upload some useful code. And you can use _FlatList_ https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html from react native package itself. No need of installing any third dependency. Also since you need right-to-left or vice-versa slided stacked items, checkout its horizontal mode property which lets you do that.